# Can we use iPhone Mapkit Framework in a web app?

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to develop a web app for iPhone on LBS.
I am using the ASP.NET MVC to do this.
Is there any way to use the Mapkit Framework provided by iPhone 3.0 in my web app ?

I am waiting to find this answer ....

Thanks and regards All.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word… no. The only way to use MapKit is in a native application on the iPhone. To achieve this with a web service, you'd need to write some kind of (XML, etc) API to your service and write a native app to communicate through it.

You can use Google Maps' JavaScript API in iPhone web apps, though - but it can be quite sluggish. You can also provide links that close Safari and open the specified location in the Maps app.